# Como limpiar una lista sin afectar otras listas

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

tratare de ser breve y directo.
Tengo dos Listas; **LisataPrimaria** y **ListaAuxiliar**. A la **ListaAuxiliar** durante un **ciclo** se le van añadiendo valores (arreglos unidimensionales), una vez terminado el ciclo, se agrega a la **ListaPrimaria** la **ListaAuxiliar**.

Luego el ciclo se repite para agregar nuevos valores a la **ListaAuxiliar**. Pero antes de esto necesito limpiar la **ListaAuxiliar** sin que se pierdan los valores de la **ListaPrimaria**.

Es para obtener al final una lista de listas.

Aqui, esta un ejemplo basico:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Inicio();
    }

    private static void Inicio()
    {
        List<List<double[]>> ListaPrimaria = new List<List<double[]>>();
        List<double[]> ListaAuxiliar = new List<double[]>();

        double[] Arreglo1 = { 741, 860, 320, 500, 820 };
        double[] Arreglo2 = { 120, 95, 45, 380, 410 };
        double[] Arreglo3 = { 720, 210, 47, 110, 1100 };
        double[] Arreglo4 = { 900, 10, 27, 1300, 60 };

        int i = 0;
        while (i < 2)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                ListaAuxiliar.Add(Arreglo1);
                ListaAuxiliar.Add(Arreglo2);
                ListaAuxiliar.Add(Arreglo4);
            }

            if (i == 1)
            {
                ListaAuxiliar.Add(Arreglo3);
            }

            ListaPrimaria.Add(ListaAuxiliar);

            ListaAuxiliar.Clear(); //Al utilizar esto se limpia tambien la ListaPrimaria.

            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como al hacer esto:

```
ListaPrimaria.Add(ListaAuxiliar);
```

Estas agregando una lista dentro de la otra, entonces necesitas una nueva lista, no limpiar la que tenes.

Al agregar una lista en la otra, no estas pasando los valores. Estas agregando efectivamente a lo que apunta ListaAuxiliar a ListaPrimaria.

Por eso, para limpiar y generar una nueva ListaAuxiliar, tenes que hacer justamente eso, generar una nueva lista.. y para generarlo, ya lo hacias antes...

```
List<double[]> ListaAuxiliar = new List<double[]>();
```

Comment: Excelente, gracias por el dato.

Answer (score 2):

Tal vez te aclare un poco entender como se asignan los valores en Java.

Para variables primitivas se asignan por valor pero para arrays y objetos se asignan por referencia como sucede en tu caso.

Cuando inicializas ListaAuxiliar, estas creando una referencia de un array en memoria, esta referencia es asignada a la variable ListaAuxiliar.

```
List<double[]> ListaAuxiliar = new List<double[]>();
```

Una referencia puede ser referenciada (valga la redundancia) por una o mas variables, Cuando agregas ListaAuxiliar a ListaPrimaria estas creando una nueva variable ListaPrimaria[x] que referencia a la misma posición de memoria que ListaAuxiliar, esto significa que puedes modificar el mismo array utilizando estas dos variables y cualquier operación que realices sobre estas dos variables se veran reflejadas en la otra porque a la final es la misma referencia.

```
ListaAuxiliar.clear();
ListaPrimaria[x].clear();
```

Ambas lineas modifican al mismo array.

Lo que necesitas hacer para reutilizar la variable ListaAuxiliar es reasignar esta variable a una nueva posición de memoria, dejando la anterior posición de memoria referenciada únicamente por la posición del array en ListaPrimaria, esto lo haces volviendo a instanciar un nuevo array asignandolo a ListaAuxiliar, en tu caso solo basta con mover esta linea

```
List<double[]> ListaAuxiliar = new List<double[]>();
```

dentro del bucle y eliminar la linea donde limpias el array porque es la que elimina los elementos en la referencia del array.

```
while (i < 2)
{
   List<double[]> ListaAuxiliar = new List<double[]>();

   if (i == 0)
   {
       ListaAuxiliar.Add(Arreglo1);
       ListaAuxiliar.Add(Arreglo2);
       ListaAuxiliar.Add(Arreglo4);
   }

   if (i == 1)
   {
       ListaAuxiliar.Add(Arreglo3);
   }

   ListaPrimaria.Add(ListaAuxiliar);

   i++;
}
```

Comment: Es c#.. la explicacion por suerte vale igual ;)

Comment: @CarlosLucero, muchas gracias por la extensa explicación, si eso mismo ya había hecho cuando leí la repuesta anterior de @gbianchi♦, en resumen, al agregar una variable a una lista,  la lista utiliza el mismo espacio de memoria de la variable.
Saludos